# Handling different Retrofit responses

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit2

I know this question has been asked a lot, but none of the answers that I've seen has helped me to clarify this issue. 
I need more of a guideline on my approach than a concrete answer.

The problem...

I receive one of the next answers from my webservices, depending if some user is founded:

```
{
    "ok": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "username": "test",
            "pass": "123",
            "reg_date": "2020-05-27 00:00:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

and...

```
{
    "error": [
        {
            "message": "No such user"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Please, correct me if I'm wrong on this definition**: Both are objects with a `String` as key and an `array` as value, and the `array`, that can be of any length, is, in this case, of type `object`

So, I need, as you may already guessed, take specific values from this responses depending on th scenario, even the `key` value ("ok" or "error"), and show in some TextView something like:

> ok, 
>   id: 1

or

> error, 
>   No such user

What I've tried until now is create a class for every object inside the list that's received:

```
public class EntityUser {
    @SerializedName("id")
    private int id;
    @SerializedName("username")
    private String username;
    @SerializedName("pass")
    private String password;
    @SerializedName("reg_date")
    private String registerDate;

    //Getters and constructor...
}
```

```
public class EntityError {
    @SerializedName("message")
    private String message;

    //Getters and constructor...
}
```

And an Api, which is, I think, where the problem is:

```
public interface JsonApi {
    @GET("SelectUser.php")
    Call<Map<String, List>> getGenericResponse();
}
```

As I've mentioned above, I suppose that what I'm getting as response is a `Map<String, List>` when `Call` is executed, but I don't know how to process this so I can get the values that I wish:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://192.168.0.35/app_android/webservices/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();

        JsonApi jsonApi = retrofit.create(JsonApi.class);
        Call<Map<String, List>> call = jsonApi.getGenericResponse();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<Map<String, List>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Map<String, List>> call, Response<Map<String, List>> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    if (response.body().containsKey("ok")){
                         //Here i need to create instance of EntityUsr so I can bind the values to his vars
                    }if(response.body().containsKey("error")){
                        //Shows an error message according to the message value
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Map<String, List>> call, Throwable t) {
                prueba.setText("Error: " + t.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

As I wrote in the code, I need to create instance of the corresponding object depending on the answer that `response` brings from the webservice, in order to get the specific values from it.

How can I do this?

Am I very lost in my approach considering the usability of Retrofit?

I don't want to chage the structure of the json received from webservice

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simple ways instead of parse it to `Map<String, List>`

1. Declare Object `UserResponse`

```
public class UserResponse {
    @SerializedName("ok")
    private ArrayList<EntityUser> users;
    @SerializedName("error")
    private ArrayList<EntityError> errors;
}
```

2. Change your API call to this

```
public interface JsonApi {
    @GET("SelectUser.php")
    Call<UserResponse> getGenericResponse();
}
```

3. Handle response when getting successfully

```
if (response.body().getUsers() != null){
   // return list users
}if(response.body().getErrors != null){
   // return list errors
}
```

Comment: Excelent, thanks a lot! But how can I now define the object of it corresponding class?
I've tried this ```EntityUsr usr = gson.fromJson(response.body().toString(), EntityUsr.class);``` but obviusly doesn't work. What should I pass or use as ```string```, or should I use ```fromJson``` method?

Comment: Do you still want to make your solution work right? Did you try my solution?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried and works perfectly identifying the response from webservice, son now my problem is to create the object, but can't figure out how..I'm trying to understand that the ```response``` is, as was defined, an ArrayList of EntityXXX, so, the object is somehow already created, just need to pass the values to an instance of it...¿?

Comment: Sure retrofit already make your entity. Because you already setup factory addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))

Comment: Yeah, works just fine!!
I've navigate through the object and its method until I've reached the methods from the object itself ```response.body().getUser().get(0).getUsername()```

Thanks A LOT!!

Comment: hmm, you make me surprise, getUser already return ArrayList, only you need is make a loop inside it and find your user :D

Comment: jajaj, yeah, I mean that navigate inside the body() elements and realize of that, it already has the methods of EntityUser.
My english isn't very good, not native XD